# Problema con la ñ al importar un csv en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente problema con laravel 5.5 y la depencia "maatwebsite/excel", cuando el controlador recibe el csv del formulario y lo convierte en una matriz.Las casillas que con tienen la letra "ñ" como niño aparecen como *null*.

```
public function alumnosImport(Request $request){
  Excel::load($request->excel, function($reader) {
    dd($reader->get());
  }
  return;
}
```

PD: resumi el codigo para mostar la matriz en pantalla

Comment: ¿En qué sistema operativo está el Excel desde el cual creaste el CSV?

Comment: w10 con formato csv(ms-dos)

Comment: ¿Cuando exportas el CSV le das codificación `UFT-8`? Sería recomendable hacerlo. ¿Si abres el CSV en un editor de textos simple como Notepad las `ñ` se ven bien?

Comment: No pero en que momento tengo que realizar la codificacion en el controlador o en la vista, y no tengo problema al revisarlo con el editor de texto de windows

Comment: Para evitar problemas, tendrías que darle la codificación `UTF-8` cuando creas el archivo CSV, que imagino será al exportarlo como CSV desde Excel, ahí debes indicar que quieres que tu archivo tenga la codificación `UTF-8`. O sea, en el proceso de exportación, antes de crear el archivo dándole un nombre, debe haber alguna opción para indicar que lo quieres con una determinada codificación. No uso Windows, así que no podría decirte con mayor exactitud.

Comment: No es problema de office, ya hice lo mismo pero con php y el formato no presento problemas

Comment: ¿O sea, tú abriste el archivo en Notepad y **las `ñ` se ven correctamente**?

Comment: Si, yo creo que el problema es de la dependecia

Comment: ¿Tú muestras los datos en una vista? ¿La misma tiene la codificación establecida a `UTF-8`?

Comment: Si, tengo un CRUD en el mismo proyecto y no presenta problemas con la Ñ

Comment: No sé si tu librería está actualizada. Ellos dicen que `UTF-8` viene por defecto. De todos modos, puedes indicarle en el `load` que te exporte en `UTF-8`, algo así, [según explican los creadores](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import#extra): `Excel::load('filename.csv', function($reader) {

}, 'UTF-8');`